# Http post from android to PHP

Tags: php, android

I am trying to do httppost form android to php through XAMPP. I am getting the httpResponse in android but there is nothing displayed when i try to load the url in browser. It only displays "NONE"

"I want to send the value from android and those must be displayed in the browser when i load the url."

```
    protected String doInBackground(String...uri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri[0]);
        //httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","somevalue"));
        Log.d("debug",nameValuePair.get(0).toString());
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair,HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // response code
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

                Log.d("response",line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Code to handle exception
        }
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("clientprotocolexception");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("IOexception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

> ................................

```
<?php

if($_POST){
    print_r($_POST);
}
else if($_GET){
    print_r($_POST);
}
else{
    echo 'NONE';
}
?>
```

Comment: When you try to load url in browser, you make another request without any post data. Explain what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to send the value from android and those must be displayed in the browser when i load the url

Comment: When you will open browser, you will always send new request. I think you need to store data on server when you make a post request, after that when you make new request from browser you must load this data.

Comment: Thank you for your instant reply. Is it possible to display the value without storing it in the server. Because i am trying to track the android device by sending the location and displaying the location in map in browser

Comment: It's easy to use GET method instead of POST. In this case you don't need to send data in code, you can simply open browser with url: "http://****/index.php?a=1". But note, when you send request in code and open browser there are two different request with two different response.

Comment: Thank you... i was always making new request from browser..MY BAD... Now i solved by storing data in database and retriving it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo $_POST['id'];//should out put "someValue"
}else{
    echo 'id is not set';
}
?>
```